# google spreadsheet as pdf e-mail attachment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with an e-mail attachment in a script.

The code:

```
//creating a new temporary spreadsheet
var tmpSpreadSheetId = SpreadsheetApp.create("attachment").getId();
var tmpSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tmpSpreadSheetId);
var tmpSheet = tmpSpreadSheet.getActiveSheet();

//copying values from another spreadsheet with the original data
var values = otherSpreadSheet.getValues();
tmpSheet.getRange(1, 1, otherSpreadSheet.getLastRow(), otherSpreadSheet.getLastColumn()).setValues(values);

//formating some numbers in the temporary spreadsheet
var lastRow = tmpSpreadSheet.getLastRow();
tmpSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 10).setBackground('#0000ff').setFontColor('white');
tmpSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 10).setBorder(null, true, null, true, null, true);
tmpSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 10).setBackground('#0000ff').setFontColor('white');
tmpSheet.getRange(2, 3, lastRow, 1).setNumberFormat("00.00%");
tmpSheet.getRange(2, 5, lastRow, 1).setNumberFormat("00.00%");
tmpSheet.getRange(2, 6, lastRow, 2).setNumberFormat("0.00");
tmpSheet.getRange(2, 8, lastRow, 1).setNumberFormat("00.00");

//logging the edited spreadsheet URL
Logger.log(tmpSpreadSheet.getUrl());

//sending an email with the spreadsheet as pdf
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(tmpSheet.getParent().getId()); 
MailApp.sendEmail('example@example.com', 'Reporting', 'bla bla bla', {attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});
```

The problem: the temporary spreadsheet looks fine.. colored and correct formatted numbers and so on,
but in the attachment it is just the plain table with wrong formatted numbers, no colors, just like the data, which were inserted to the tempSheet at the beginning.

Hopefully you understand my problem, I have no idea at all, what the problem could be, I tried to fix it for 2-3 hours, but now I would need help :)

Thanks in advance and a good week
Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there with your script. You just need to add **SpreadsheetApp.flush();** before you send the email and just after you have done the formatting (see code below). 
The Utilities.sleep() is a good suggestion by @Amit but it will not work with your code as it needs to be flushed to be updated, unfortunately, sleep will just slow down the code as it doesn't work like setTimeout() (I have tried it).

Anyway here is the code, I have edited it slightly but in essence the only difference is the **SpreadsheetApp.flush()** . If you need any further help just let me know :)

```
    function myfunction() {
  // otherSpreadSheet details
  var otherSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id").getSheets()[0];

  //creating a new temporary spreadsheet
  var tmpSpreadSheetId = SpreadsheetApp.create("attachment");
  var tmpSheet = tmpSpreadSheetId.getSheets()[0];

  //copying values from another spreadsheet with the original data
  var values = otherSpreadSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  tmpSheet
    .getRange(
      1,
      1,
      otherSpreadSheet.getLastRow(),
      otherSpreadSheet.getLastColumn()
    )
    .setValues(values);

  //formating some numbers in the temporary spreadsheet
  var lastRow = tmpSheet.getLastRow(); // **last row had an error in the script here
  tmpSheet
    .getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 10)
    .setBackground("#0000ff")
    .setFontColor("white");
  tmpSheet
    .getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 10)
    .setBorder(null, true, null, true, null, true);
  tmpSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 10).setBackground("#0000ff").setFontColor("white");
  tmpSheet.getRange(2, 3, lastRow, 1).setNumberFormat("00.00%");
  tmpSheet.getRange(2, 5, lastRow, 1).setNumberFormat("00.00%");
  tmpSheet.getRange(2, 6, lastRow, 2).setNumberFormat("0.00");
  tmpSheet.getRange(2, 8, lastRow, 1).setNumberFormat("00.00");

  // USE SpreadsheetApp.flush() to update the sheet before you send it as a PDF,
  // this will allow you to apply the formatting and any other functions.
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var fileID = tmpSheet.getParent().getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
  MailApp.sendEmail("EMAIL HERE", "Reporting", "bla bla bla", {
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding a delay with Utilities.sleep() before sending the email. Also replace:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(tmpSheet.getParent().getId());
```

with:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(tmpSpreadSheet);
```

Comment: I tried sleep and it wasn't a solution for this case